# Android WebView CSS float

Tags: android, webview, floating

Our team is really struggeling right now.
We got a customer and he is giving us some HTML files. In these HTML files there is some text and an image, floated right with a width of 50%. On a mobile it works great and on most tablets too, but not on the samsung galaxy 10.1 or galaxy 10.1n. It works fine on the emulator, even with 10 inch devices.

Our problem is, that the `WebView` puts the image on top of the text. It ignores the floating.
Unfortunately we can't change the HTML-files by ourselves because the resources are used on the iPhone and on a webapp. Only android has a problem with that.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: You should post an example for quicker responses.

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same issues, including several odd problems with Samsung Galaxy S4+ being the only Android phone not responding consistently like other test phones to traditional CSS like float, position, top etc...

The only way I've found to consistently get around these issues is to use TABLES and % for width to control the resizable layout.

Yes, I know tables are deprecated. But they have default properties that are very useful and  there are still no HTML5 equivalents that are consistent across devices as the trusty table...